# Not uploading images in etsy shop with rss feed when relative path is given

Tags: wordpress, rss, etsy

I am trying to generate feeds for products that i have and share it in etsy shop. I have done following things to do so. The function to perform this task is:

For Submitting the products list:

```
    function submit_listing_to_etsy()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . "etcpf_listings";
        $id = false;
        if ($this->check_unsubmitted_listing()) {
            $id = $this->listing['id'];

            $data = maybe_unserialize($this->listing['data']);
            $listing_id = '';
            $type = false;
            if (!(NULL == $this->listing['listing_id'])) {
                $listing_id = '/'.$this->listing['listing_id']; 
                $type = true;
            } 
            unset($data['image']);

            if (isset($data['sku'])) {
                unset($data['sku']); // it is not supported yet
            }
            unset($data['image']);
            if (count($data['tags']) == 1) { // check if tags with 0 value is set
                unset($data['tags']);
            }
            $weight = explode(' ', $data['item_weight']);
            if (isset($weight[1])) {
                $data['item_weight'] = $weight[0];
                $data['item_weight_units'] = $weight[1];
            }

            $length = explode(' ',$data['item_length']);
            if (isset($length[1])) {
                $data['item_length'] = $length[0];
                $data['item_length_units'] = $length[1];
            }

            $width = explode(' ',$data['item_width']);
            if (isset($width[1])) {
                $data['item_width'] = $width[0];
                $data['item_width_units'] = $width[1];
            }

            $height = explode(' ',$data['item_height']);
            if (isset($height[1])) {
                $data['item_height'] = $height[0];
                $data['item_height_units'] = $height[1];
            }

            $data['language'] = substr(get_locale(), 0,2);
            $url = "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings".$listing_id."?scopes=listings_w";
            $acc_req = $this->prepareHash($url,'POST',$type);
            // $response = $this->browsePost($acc_req,json_encode($data),true);
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $acc_req);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $result = json_decode($response);
            $result = $result->results;    
            $listing = $result[0];
            $this->listing_id = $listing->listing_id;

            if ($this->listing_id) {
                $data = [
                    'listing_id' => $this->listing_id,
                    'upload_result'   => maybe_serialize($listing),
                    'uploaded'      => (strlen($listing_id) > 0) ? 2 : 1
                ];

            } else 
                $data = [
                    'upload_result'     => maybe_serialize($response),
                    'uploaded'          => 3
                ];

            $wpdb->update($table,$data,['id'=>$id]); 
        }
    }
```

For Submitting the images for those products:

```
     function submit_listing_images(){
        $data = maybe_unserialize($this->listing['data']);
        $image = $data['image'];

        global $wpdb;
        $tbl = $wpdb->prefix . "etcpf_listings";

        $this->check_unsubmitted_listing(1);

        $url =  "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/".$this->listing['listing_id']."/images";

        $wp_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $i = str_replace($wp_dir['url'],$wp_dir['path'],$image);


        if ($i == $image)
            $i = str_replace($wp_dir['baseurl'], $wp_dir['basedir'], $image);
        $img_type = wp_check_filetype($image);
        $url_to_send = $this->prepareHash($url,'POST');
        $data = [
            'image'    => '@'.$i.';type='.$img_type['type']
        ];
        if (!$i) {
            $wpdb->update($tbl,['uploaded' => 2],['id'=>$this->listing['id']]);   
            return;
        }
        //print_r($data);exit;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_to_send);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: multipart/form-data"]);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $result = json_decode($response);
        $result = $result->results;
        $img_data = $result[0];
        $listing_image_id = $img_data->listing_image_id;

        if ($listing_image_id) {
            $wpdb->update($tbl,['listing_image_id'=>$listing_image_id,'uploaded' => 2],['id'=>$this->listing['id']]);   
        }
    }
```

The generated feeds is as under:

```
    <rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
    <title>test</title>
    <link>...</link>
    <item>
    <id>41</id>
    <title>
    <![CDATA[ Ship Your Idea ]]>
    </title>
    <item_group_id>40</item_group_id>
    <quantity>10</quantity>
    <description>
    <![CDATA[
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
    ]]>
    </description>
    <price>35.00</price>
    <image_link>
    http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/hoodie_7_front.jpg
    </image_link>
    <etsy_category>
    <![CDATA[ Baby Carriers & Wraps:69150455 ]]>
    </etsy_category>
    <weight_unit>kg</weight_unit>
    <dimension_unit>cm</dimension_unit>
    <tags/>
    <currency>NPR</currency>
    </item>
    <item>
    <id>42</id>
    <title>
    <![CDATA[ Ship Your Idea ]]>
    </title>
    <item_group_id>40</item_group_id>
    <quantity>10</quantity>
    <description>
    <![CDATA[
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
    ]]>
    </description>
    <price>35.00</price>
    <image_link>
    http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/hoodie_1_front.jpg
    </image_link>
    <sale_price>30.00</sale_price>
    <etsy_category>
    <![CDATA[ Baby Carriers & Wraps:69150455 ]]>
    </etsy_category>
    <weight_unit>kg</weight_unit>
    <dimension_unit>cm</dimension_unit>
    <tags/>
    <currency>NPR</currency>
    </item>
    <item>
    <id>47</id>
    <title>
    <![CDATA[ Woo Ninja ]]>
    </title>
    <quantity>10</quantity>
    <description>
    <![CDATA[
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
    ]]>
    </description>
    <price>35.00</price>
    <image_link>
    http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/hoodie_2_front.jpg
    </image_link>
    <etsy_category>
    <![CDATA[ Baby Carriers & Wraps:69150455 ]]>
    </etsy_category>
    <weight_unit>kg</weight_unit>
    <dimension_unit>cm</dimension_unit>
    <tags/>
    <currency>NPR</currency>
    </item>
    </channel>
    </rss>
```

The path in this generated feed is okay. When i copy and paste the image path, it loads the images. But to the etsy api, relative path is sent. While I print the data that contains image path it returns array something like this:

```
    Array ( [image] => @/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/hoodie_1_front.jpg;type=image/jpeg )
```

And when i check it in the respective folder, the particular image exists.So Can anyone help me out what is the real issue here? Th interesting part is, sometimes from some computer image is also sent and it despays in etsy shop. What is the real issue here? Thanks in advance.

**IF You Want Anything More To Understand. Please comment.**

Answer (score 0):

Etsy does not support localhost images URL, So your first upload this image globally (on Amazon S3 etc).

```
<image_link>
 open(https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/hoodie_2_front.jpg)
</image_link>
```

Comment: $url =  "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/".$this->listing['listing_id']."/images";

        $wp_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $i = str_replace($wp_dir['url'],$wp_dir['path'],$image);


        if ($i == $image)
            $i = str_replace($wp_dir['baseurl'], $wp_dir['basedir'], $image);
        $img_type = wp_check_filetype($image);
        $url_to_send = $this->prepareHash($url,'POST');
        $data = [
            'image'    => '@'.$i.';type='.$img_type['type']
        ];
this code was supposed to upload the image to the etsy for that particular listings